# using compressor with tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce, minify

reviewing the code example on this page, it seem like the example is initializing both twice

http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Compressor/ASPX

Example of initialization

The example below will pack both themes and all plugins into one file/steam. Remove the things you don't need or add you custom plugins to the settings below. Remember that the tinyMCE_GZ.init call must be placed in it's own script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_gzip.js">       </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE_GZ.init({
plugins : 'style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras',
themes : 'simple,advanced',
languages : 'en',
disk_cache : true,
debug : false
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
.. your normal init ..
});
</script>
```

is it correct that you have to call tinyMCE.init AND tinyMCE_GZ.init ?  this seems odd.

i ask this question because when i remove the tinyMCE.init it doesn't seem to work but i want to ensure i am not defeating the purpose and loading both the optimized version and the non optimized version.tiny

if this is the case, should the init calls be identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it correct that you have to call
>   tinyMCE.init AND tinyMCE_GZ.init ?
>   this seems odd.

Yes, you have to, cause tinyMCE.init initialized the tinymeditor and tinyMCE_GZ.init is used for something else (gzip).